# is it possible to get the input device details in http request

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest

I am trying to get details of input device from which the request is made.

May I know, if this is possible using httpservlet request object.

Comment: What info you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get the details you're after by retrieving the User-Agent header from the HttpServletRequest object:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String browserType = request.getHeader("User-Agent"); // This is the line you're after

    // This will just output the user agent to the browser
    response.getOutputStream().write(browserType.getBytes());
    response.getOutputStream().close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at HTTP header [USER-AGENT](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#user-agent)  and [headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html)

> This line if present gives the software program used by the original client. This is for statistical purposes and the tracing of protocol violations. It should be included. The first white space delimited word must be the software product name, with an optional slash and version designator. Other products which form part of the user agent may be put as separate words.

```
  <field>   =   User-Agent: <product>+
    <product> =   <word> [/<version>]
    <version> =   <word>
```

Example:

```
           User-Agent:  LII-Cello/1.0  libwww/2.5
```

To get them

```
Header[] allHeaders = req.getAllHeaders();
```

Each header object contains name and value.

Comment: @brettw Some times may not :)

Answer (score 1):

The User-agent header is the best you are going to get.  However, you should not treat this header as "gospel truth".  It is routinely spoofed, for a variety of reasons.  (Indeed, there are web browser plug-ins/add-ons that are specifically designed to help the user do this!)

Mapping a user-agent string to browser and operating system is a heuristic process.  You are best of looking for an existing Java library to do it for you.